# ImportError: cannot import name _imaging Accessing from Django Admin Pillow

Tags: python, django, django-admin, importerror, python-imaging-library

I have been struggling with the error for two days, tried all the answers from stack overflow but no luck. I have a simple model which use Django image field

```
class Author(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    email = models.EmailField()
    url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    short_bio = models.TextField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    long_bio = models.TextField(max_length=5000, blank=True, null=True)
    role = models.ManyToManyField(AuthorRole)
    facebook_link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    linkedin_link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    twitter_link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    gplus_link = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',     default='images/user_default.jpg')
```

In production server when I am accessing the model from admin and select an image and try to save, its throwing the following error. I installed and uninstalled pillow several times. Tried different version of django and pillow. By the way its working fine in local environment.

```
[:error] [pid 20256:tid 139822013380352] [remote 72.48.102.12:60881]
from PIL import Image
[:error] [pid 20256:tid 139822013380352] [remote 72.48.102.12:60881]       File"/home/.virtualenvs/wcsenvpython3/lib/python3.4/sitepackages/PIL/Image.py",    line 67, in <module>
[:error] [pid 20256:tid 139822013380352] [remote 72.48.102.12:60881]
from PIL import _imaging as core
[:error] [pid 20256:tid 139822013380352] [remote 72.48.102.12:60881] ImportError:cannot import name _imaging
```

I can do `from PIL import _imaging` from manage.py shell. So it looks like pythonpath is configured properly.[image]

Inside my virtualenv I can see the _imaging.cpython-34m.so file, but there is no
_imaging.py file.[image]

My server is hosted in linode. It's Ubuntu 14.04. I am using Apache2. Python 3.4.3. Django 1.10 Pillow 3.3.0. You kind help is very much appreciable. This error is bugging me for long time.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWHW9.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/nH8O3.jpg   [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3CmfK.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vpdoe.jpg

Comment: What command did you use to re-install Pillow?

Comment: pip uninstall Pillow and then pip install Pillow. Thanks for your response. I found the answer. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I got the answer at last. It has nothing to do with Pillow. I gave write permission for public to 'media' folder where images are saved and suddenly it solved the problem. I am not sure if it's a security vulnerability but it solves the error.

**How did I find it:**
I decided to change the Image.py file from PIL.

```
  try:
    # If the _imaging C module is not present, Pillow will not load.
    # Note that other modules should not refer to _imaging directly;
    # import Image and use the Image.core variable instead.
    # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
    # and should be considered private and subject to change.
    from PIL import _imaging as core
    if PILLOW_VERSION != getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None):
        raise ImportError("The _imaging extension was built for another "
                          " version of Pillow or PIL")

except ImportError as v:
    core = _imaging_not_installed()
    # Explanations for ways that we know we might have an import error
    if str(v).startswith("Module use of python"):
        # The _imaging C module is present, but not compiled for
        # the right version (windows only).  Print a warning, if
        # possible.
        warnings.warn(
            "The _imaging extension was built for another version "
            "of Python.",
            RuntimeWarning
            )
    elif str(v).startswith("The _imaging extension"):
        warnings.warn(str(v), RuntimeWarning)
    elif "Symbol not found: _PyUnicodeUCS2_" in str(v):
        # should match _PyUnicodeUCS2_FromString and
        # _PyUnicodeUCS2_AsLatin1String
        warnings.warn(
            "The _imaging extension was built for Python with UCS2 support; "
            "recompile Pillow or build Python --without-wide-unicode. ",
            RuntimeWarning
            )
    elif "Symbol not found: _PyUnicodeUCS4_" in str(v):
        # should match _PyUnicodeUCS4_FromString and
        # _PyUnicodeUCS4_AsLatin1String
        warnings.warn(
            "The _imaging extension was built for Python with UCS4 support; "
            "recompile Pillow or build Python --with-wide-unicode. ",
            RuntimeWarning
            )
    # Fail here anyway. Don't let people run with a mostly broken Pillow.
    # see docs/porting.rst
    raise
```

The except block is checking few conditions and last line is raising import error again. I commented out `raise` , and bingo it showed me permission error. 
I don't know why in earth it shows import error while the problem is permission. I would expect the writers of pillow to look at the matter and try to generate relevant error message while problem is not really import error rather permission error.